# Solving $\Delta u\equiv0$ on $x^2+y^2\leq1$ with $u_r(1,\theta)=3\sin(2 \theta)+1$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

The general solution to $\Delta u\equiv0$ on $x^2+y^2\leq 1$ is known to be $$u(r,\theta)=\frac{\alpha_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} r^n\left(\alpha_n \cos(n\theta)+\beta_n \sin(n\theta)\right)$$

Here $r\in [0,1]$ and $\theta\in[-\pi,\pi)$. Applying $u_r(1,\theta)=3\sin(2\theta)+1$ yields $$3\sin(2\theta)+1=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left((n\alpha_n)\cos(n\theta)+(n\beta_n)\sin(n\theta)\right)$$ If we multiply both sides by $d\theta$ and integrate from $\theta=-\pi$ to $\theta=\pi$ we get $1=0$ which is absurd.

Do you think there is a typo in this problem, or is there a flaw with my logic?

Comment: Where did the constant term go and why is it $(n\alpha_n)$ and not $(\alpha_n)$?

Comment: It's because we took a derivative of $u$ with respect to $r$ and then plugged in $r=1$

Comment: Your argument isn't flawed: By the divergence theorem, for any nice function $u$, you have $$\int_D \Delta u\, dxdy= \int_{\partial D} \partial_r u \, d\sigma,$$where $D$ is the unit disk, and $\partial D$ it's boundary. Since your $u$ is harmonic, the left hand side is 0, and so your Neumann boundary condition should have this integral vanishing (it's called a compatibility condition). Since your particular condition doesn't, it means the problem is not solvable.

Comment: @Matthew Sorry yes, didn't notice the subscript $r$